# Trouble Adding Background Image to JFrame in Netbeans 7.0

Tags: java, swing, jframe

This is my first question, so please bear with me.

I am working on an application (which I have already fully-designed). Now I am at the coding stage and I am having trouble placing a background image on the JFrame while still allowing it to play its role as a Container so I can put buttons on it and things of that nature.

I have created this JFrame class file in Netbeans 7.0 and if someone could tell me how to do this through the interface of Netbeans that would be great (if not, just the code would be fine).

I already know that I am supposed to override the paintComponent method (which I have done already, but my image file is not showing). Also I have a second questions, I don't want to put the full file-path for the image, I have my source files in packages and now I am quite confused as to where I am to put my image files.

EDIT: **initComponoents**() is the generated method by Netbeans that determines the properties of the JFrame.

```
public class TinyTowerOrganizerInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form TinyTowerOrganizerInterface */
    Image backgroundImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("D:/Java/TinyTowerOrganizer/Images/Background.jpg");

public TinyTowerOrganizerInterface() throws IOException {

    initComponents(); 
    class BackgroundPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel{
        private Image image;
        public BackgroundPanel(Image image){
            this.image = image;
        }
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        }

    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Tiny Tower Organizer");
    setFont(new java.awt.Font("Pixelated", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(900, 500));
    setName("frame"); // NOI18N
    setResizable(false);
    setUndecorated(true);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 900, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 500, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                new TinyTowerOrganizerInterface().setVisible(true);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TinyTowerOrganizerInterface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What does `initComponents()` do?

Comment: I have made an edit in my original post that says what it does. "initComponoents() is the generated method by Netbeans that determines the properties of the JFrame."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I already know that I am supposed to override the paintComponent method

JFrame does not have a paintComponent(...) method.

Instead you should extend JPanel (or JComponent) and add your custom painting in the paintComponent() method. Then you add the panel to the frame.

Also, don't forget to override the getPreferredSize() method of the panel to return the size of the image.

Edit:

First of all when you post code post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can copy and execute the code. I've include a simple SSCCE below.

There are different problems.

The first problem is that the getImage() method reads the image async so when the frame is displayed, the image is not completely loaded and there is nothing to display as you can see when run the code. Instead use ImageIO to read the image.

> What is it that I even want to get accomplished

When you make the above change and run the code you will still only see a small frame even though pack() have been invoked. That is because you haven't added any components to the poanel so the default preferred size is (10, 10) because you are using a FlowLayout. So you need to override the getPreferredSize() method to return the size of the image so the panel can be packed properly.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class MyApplication extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

/** Creates new form MyApplication */
    Image backgroundImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("mong.jpg");

    public MyApplication() throws IOException
    {

        this.setContentPane(new JPanel()
        {

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
        });

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        new MyApplication();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the paintComponent method of the JPanel, if you looked at the code it would've displayed what I meant. I just need to know what is wrong with the current code that I have right now. There are no compile errors or anything, but it just doesn't display my image (which is in the correct path as stated).

Comment: Sorry, I did look at the code but I looked like you where trying to extend the paintComponent() method of the frame. The problem would be that you draw the image, then you invoke the normal panel painting logic which over paints the image with the panel background. super.paintComponent() should be the first statement.

Comment: Okay, I had seen in a previous question of the same nature of mine that the order should be in the way that I have put it, but if it isn't supposed to be that way then I will change it. But now you have really now left me with more questions that I had to start with. So I extended JPanel with my own JPanel class. I did override the paintComponent method with my code and added the panel to the frame and still no luck. How would I successfully override the getPreferredSize method to do what I want? (What is it that I even want to get accomplished?)

Comment: Okay, I added the SSCCE. I am just extremely confused as to how to override the setPreferredSize. What code do I place inside the method?

Comment: That is not a SSCCE, the code doesn't compile. You haven't changed the I/O yet. You didn't add a pack() so you can't even test to see if the getPreferredSize() method is working. The getPreferredSize() method returns a Dimension object which would be the width/height of the image that is being painted.

Comment: Okay, so there, I added all of the code necessary for it to compile. I apologize for not adding the initComponents function beforehand.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have time for this. I gave you some simple code  based on the original code you posted. I then told you the two things you needed to change, the I/O and the getPreferredSize() method. Intead you post back more complicated code that doesn't implement either of the suggestions I made (I will not write the code for you). I'm not sure why you define a new class since you never use it anywhere. Maybe the problem is the IDE? I suggest you start with my SSCCE add the I/O and then the getPreferredSize() method. Once you understand the basics then add the changes to your real code.

Comment: Well that is the code that is generated by Netbeans as I had stated in my original post. Okay, I apologize, I have just been looking around for such a long period of time for the answer to my question that I was practically stuck. But I think I can get myself going from here, I appreciate the help. Thanks again, and sorry for being bothersome if I was.